# Где взять POSIX стандарт?

Tags: c, стандарт, posix

Хочу написать маленькую libc для своего микро-дистрибутива linux по POSIX стандарту, после гугления я понял, что его принимает IEEE, если нет, то поправите меня, ибо я не особо в этих стандартизациях разобрался.

На сайте IEEE платный.

Как писать по этому стандарту бесплатно, и где взять актуальную версию стандарта?

Comment: Стандарт C++ также платный. На мой взгляд это позор и нарушение прав программистов тем более, что многие программисты принимают участие в развитии языка. Поэтому я отрицательно отношусь к Страуструпу.

Comment: Когда-то тогда еще никому неизвестный финский паренёк запостил где-то подобное сообщение...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow черновики стандарта бесплатны и этого для некоммерческого использования, имхо, достаточно. О причинах платности итоговой версии стандарта написано в [FAQ ISO](http://www.iso.org/iso/ru/home/faqs/faqs_standards.htm?=).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

некоторые важные версии публикуются для свободного доступа на сайте организации [the open group](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Open_Group).

например:

1. [The Single UNIX® Specification, Version 2 © 1997 The Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/)
2. [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition © 2001-2004 The IEEE and The Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/)
3. [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 IEEE Std 1003.1™, 2013 Edition © 2001-2013 The IEEE and The Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)